# Using apply on an array of objects in a json

Tags: json, r, apply, lapply, sapply

I have a json which I am reading in R and converting to a list object. For a key "metrics", there is an array of multiple objects of the same type.
Json structure:

```
{"metrics":[{"metricName":"abc",
             "metricType":"def"
            },
            {"metricName":"ghi",
             "metricType":"jkl"
            }]
}
```

This is how my list object looks like:

```
$metrics
$metrics[[1]]
$metrics[[1]]$metricName
[1] "abc"

$metrics[[1]]$metricType
[1] "def"


$metrics[[2]]
$metrics[[2]]$metricName
[1] "ghi"

$metrics[[2]]$metricType
[1] "jkl"
```

I want to apply a function (someFunc) to each object of the array. $metrics[[1]],$metrics[[2]]. How can this be done using apply family of functions?

```
somefunc(x){return(list(x$metricName,x$metricType)}
```

I tried concatenating like this:

```
lapply(lapply(metrics,"["),someFunc)
```

This does not throw an error but gives empty lists as output. The someFunc expects x$metricName,x$metricType objects to process. But using "[" does not render that kind of object I guess. Can this be handled using the apply functions?

Comment: What about `lapply(metrics, FUN=function(element){someFunc(el$metricName,el$metricType)}`

Comment: @EricLecoutre this again is gives out empty lists. No error thrown.

Comment: Cf my post in answers section

Answer (score 0):

Can you explici what your function someFunc is doing (and its parameters)?

This is working for me

```
 someFunc=function(metricName,metricType){
     return(paste(metricName,metricType))
     }
metrics=list(list(metricName="abc",metricType="m"),
             list(metricName="gg",metricType="L"))

lapply(metrics,FUN=function(el){someFunc(el$metricName,el$metricType)})
```

(use `sapply` eventually if you want to have a vector.

Comment: this is my someFunc:   `format<-function(x){
  metricName=sapply(x,FUN = "[[","metricName")
  metricType=sapply(x,FUN = "[[","metricType")
  tagsData=sapply(x,FUN = "[[","tagsData",simplify = F)
  aggregator=sapply(x,FUN = "[[","aggregator",simplify = F)
  return(mapply(FUN = list,metricName=metricName,metricType=metricType,tagsData=tagsData,aggregator=aggregator,SIMPLIFY = F))
}`

Comment: Can you detail on your example what type of outcome you expect?

Comment: Got it now. There was no need to use lapply here. Just passed the "metrics" object to my format function and it worked. Thanks for your help!!!